# Quickest way to pass data to a popup window I created using window.open()?

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code to open a popup window using the window.open() function.  I'd like to pass data from the parent window to that popup window and I can't seem to find an elegant or simple solution anywhere on google or SO, but it seems like there should be support for this built into JS.  What's the easiest way to pass data to the popup window?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: What kind of data? Primitives? (strings, Numbers, bools) Or objects?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Due to security restrictions it *is* super easy *only* if the parent window and the popup are from the same domain. If that is the case just use this:

```
// Store the return of the `open` command in a variable
var newWindow = window.open('http://www.mydomain.com');

// Access it using its variable
newWindow.my_special_setting = "Hello World";
```

In the child (popup) window, you could access that variable like this:

```
window.my_special_setting
```

Was there something specific you wanted to do past that?

Comment: Might have to use `newWindow.window.myVariable = ...` in the parent and `myVariable` in the child window.

Comment: I think just `myWindow.myVariable = ...` would work well?

Answer (score 4):

In the parent use:

```
let newWindow = window.open('http://www.example.com');
newWindow["myVar"] = "Hello World"
```

In the Child use: `window["myVar"]` to access it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's the same domain, do what Bart said. If it's a different domain, you can use the hash tag to pass some data, eg http://www.example.com/page#some_data_for_the_page. You could URL encode key/value pairs if you have enough data to warrant that.

Comment: Given this answer is almost 8 years old, is this CORS friendly? Purley out of curiosity.

Comment: @MarkCarpenterJr No, not at all - all of the data being sent to that page is in the URL or in cookies. That being said, some use cases may not require stringent CSRF checks - especially if data is just being displayed, and nothing is being saved. In those cases, this should be safe.

Comment: It's easy enough to pass small amounts of data as URL encoded arguments. The challenge is when the data to pass exceeds 8K. So far, the local storage solution doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

You could also set the variable as the 'name' attribute in open.window function and then use window.name in the new window to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

There has some ways:

1. Use `window.localStorage`, set the data in origin window and get the data in the popup window.
2. Attach to the URL as query param.
3. Doug Neiner mentioned above:

```
// Store the return of the `open` command in a variable
var newWindow = window.open('http://www.example.com');

// Access it using its variable
newWindow.my_special_setting = "Hello World";

// In the child (popup) window, you could access that variable like this:
window.my_special_setting
```

Comment: The local storage solution works on current versions of Chrome, Edge and Firefox. This should be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to pass small amounts of data as URL encoded arguments. The challenge is when the data to pass exceeds 8K. The local storage solution is simplest, and works on current versions of Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

In the calling program:

```
localStorage.setItem('testing', "a very long and rather important test string");
open('callee_test.html');
```

In the callee JS script:

```
const mydata = localStorage.getItem('testing') || null;
if (mydata) localStorage.removeItem('testing');
```

Answer (score -3):

`theWindow.someVar = "bla";`