# Passing variable to the new popup window

Tags: php, forms, popup, href

I have a table in which there are small href links assigned in each row which i have set using below code working fine:

```
<a href="popup.php" onclick="javascript:void window.open('popup.php','1361166642895','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,left=0,top=0');return false;"><h10>(check status)</h10></a>
```

Now I do not want to display the same above href link as static but want to send my variable value to the pop window and need to get data displayed separately for each row. 
In short i want to pass my variable `$name` in the popup window. I am trying below code but but isn't happening. Even i tried `<FORM>` by  `GET`

```
<?php echo "<a href=popup.php?id=",$name,"><h10>(check status)</h10></a>";?>
```

On popup.php page:

```
<?php echo $id = $_GET["id"]; ?>
```

What i want want is to pass variable using any method (GET or HREF), and it should open in new popup window not in next tab or forwarded window

Comment: Try <?php echo $id = $_GET["id"]; ?>

Comment: @vinod, already tried

Comment: what does var_dump($_POST); give you? actually a $_GET is what you want based on your url.

Comment: Poassible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830347/quickest-way-to-pass-data-to-a-popup-window-i-created-using-window-open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
 <?php echo "<a href=popup.php?id=",$name,"><h10>(check status)</h10></a>";?>
```

to

```
<?php echo "<a target='_blank' href='popup.php?id=".$name."' onclick=\"window.open(this.href, 'popupwindow', width=400,height=300,scrollbars,resizable');return false;\"><h10>(check status)</h10></a>";?>
                                    ^              ^     ^ ^// here was the mistake
```

You have not concatenated the strings properly and you missed `'` for `herf` attribute.

Use `target="_blank"` for opening link in new tab or new browser.

Comment: thanks it passing values now. but after click its opening to its fowarded window. Can i open that in new window?

Comment: @ Yogesh, thanks!! i meant in new popup window, its opening in new separate window

Comment: @ Yogesh, Please let me know how to get it in popup window