# Why isn't my session variable being passed to popup?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, popup

I have researched a lot on this and found one similar question (see [Passing variable to the new popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972720/passing-variable-to-the-new-popup-window)) but I still cannot pass my session variable to a popup. In brief, I am trying to incorporate a rudimentary comments popup box into my website so users can post comments while viewing different parts of the home page. I have a home page (home.php) from which user clicks a link to a popup window. Note the session variables work fine on home.php for every other aspect of the page. User clicks comments popup box on home.php to open usercomments.php as follows (popup opens without a problem; the relevant code for home.php follows):

```
<?php session_start();

include 'connect.php';

$_SESSION['login_id'];
$_SESSION['user'];

**$AjaxUser** = $_SESSION['user']; //All bolded text only added here for clarity

?>

//Lots of code

<div id="commentsbox"<?php echo "<a     
href='http://www.website.com/usercomments.php?id=".**$AjaxUser**."'    
onclick=\"wopen('http://www.website.com/usercomments.php', 'popupname',   
'width=600,height=600,scrollbars');return false;\"><img src=\"images/comments.png\"   
style=\"float:right; margin-right:5px\" height=\"22\" width=\"22\"></a>";?></div>
```

Am I wrong in thinking $AjaxUser was passed to usercomments.php? In the popup usercomments.php, user posts a comment which displays with no problems. However, the username does not display along with the post (note: when incorporating similar code into an existing page on the site and NOT as a popup, the username of the person who posts is correctly displayed...more evidence that the session variable is not passed to the popup). Here is the php and AJAX code for usercomments.php:

```
<?php session_start();

include 'connect.php'; 

$_GET['$AjaxUser'];

$user=$_GET['$AjaxUser'];

?>
//lots of code
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){

            alert("Problem encountered");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

                    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}

    var user = "<**?php echo $user;** ?>";
    var usercomment = document.getElementById('usercomment').value;


var queryString = "?usercomment=" + usercomment + "&user" + user;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "AJAX_test.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

Or is my problem with the way I am trying to GET $AjaxUser, or even the way I am assigning var user in the AJAX code above? My guess is $AjaxUser is not even passing from home.php, because when I input $user into the comments field in usercomments.php as follows:

```
 <input type='text' id='usercomment' value='<?php echo $user ?>' />
```

the input field is blank. I would appreciate greatly any help as I am new to AJAX!

Comment: One thing to watch for  with sessions is making sure you are on the same domain. For example: if you set the variable on www.domain.com, then your header in the php file is returning you to domain.com, your session information will not translate, you need to send header to www.domain.com. Check through your code to make sure this isn't the case. I see above  you left off the http:// on one redirect, so it is possible the issue is inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Hayes....I mistakenly left off the http:// only here on Stack Overflow. I will re-check my code.

Comment: When your ajax page receives and sets the session info, it will be like this: $_SESSION['user'] = $_GET['user']; Then you'll be able to use that session variable on any page hat has session_start(); at the top of it.

Comment: Another thing to note is that even if you set the Session variable with Ajax, the current page will not have use of the session variable until the page is reloaded because each loaded page is static. If you want to be able to use the session info on the pop up, make sure the ajax call that is returned was completed before opening the new window. You may be opening the new window before the session is set and therefore not having it available when it loads. ( but if that is the case it will be available on subsequent loads )

Comment: Hi @Gary Hayes...I am carefully reading your posts to try and learn more about this topic as I am still relatively new (6 weeks) to php...thanks for your great info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the `$_GET['variable']` correctly. `$_GET` is defined by PHP based on URL parameters such as `?this=that&thisother=another`.

The `$_SESSION` variable stands a lone by itself and will be accessible wherever you call `session_start();`

Just try...

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
```

Instead of all the other declarations on the ajax page. Being sure to include session_start(); at the top of that page as well.

Lastly I don't see you assigning anything to `$_SESSION['user']` so make sure you assign something to that variable like an id or whatever it is you're trying to use.

If you are however insisting on passing this information using the `$_GET` parameter. The `?id` part is the key you're looking to reference on the other page. So instead of `$_GET['**$AjaxUser**']` just `$_GET['id']`.