# Passed data on selected row from dialog window to main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#1, #2').click(function(){
        window.clickedbtnid = $(this).attr('id');
        $( "#table_dialog_1" ).dialog();
    });
    $( "#table_dialog_1" ).find('td').click(function(){ $('#'+window.clickedbtnid).parent().prev().find('input').val($(this).id);
        $( "#table_dialog_1" ).dialog('close');
    })
});
```

`$('#input_'+id).attr('value', $(this).html());`

this was closed to what i want but it only pass based on clicked `td's` text of table on dialog area because what I need is the `first td` table of dialog window to pass on `input tag`, and `second td` and `third` on `link tag element`. See my last table in fiddle below, it should look like the table on the main page when dialog window is closed.

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zo89a94o/5/)

Comment: please rewrite the section on what you expect code to do, it is not very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zo89a94o/6/) is what you are looking for, I refactored the code a bit, added class `clickMe` to button, it makes id unnecessary.

the JS code

```
var clickedButton;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.clickMe').click(function(){
    clickedButton = this;
    $( "#table_dialog_1" ).dialog();        
});
$( '#table_dialog_1 tr').click(function(){ 
    var  tds = $(this).children();
    $(clickedButton).parent().prev().find('input').val(tds.eq(0).html());
    $(clickedButton).next('a').text(tds.eq(2).html()+','+tds.eq(1).html());
    $( "#table_dialog_1" ).dialog('close');
});
});
```

Comment: Yes, i also looking for code that will disregards `id's`.Thanks.

Comment: In this example,im using jquery ui dialog, but will need it in simple window.open("page here"), but thanks.

Comment: Hi,why does  $(clickedButton).parent().prev().find('input').val(tds.eq(0).html()); always returning null , im using window.open(page.jsp) and not jquiery ui dialog

Comment: i am assuming tds is element in the new window, and you are trying to access from parent window, i do not think that is possible, you can look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830347/quickest-way-to-pass-data-to-a-popup-window-i-created-using-window-open/1830388#1830388,

Comment: so ` $(clickedButton).parent().prev()` not applicable for window.open?

Comment: Actually i do have codes  opener.window.f1.txtInput1.value = tds.eq(0).html(); but it olny work if table has only one row.

Comment: @bumbumpaw without looking at your code, i cannot tell what is wrong, but if you are using a new window, once some row is clicked, you need to call a method of the parent window, and pass the row data to it, and then call window.close(), take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276086/popup-window-to-return-data-to-parent-on-close