# Pass value to popup window

Tags: javascript, html, windows, popupwindow

I have some text field  for send to popup window ( I want send productPrice and productName) :

```
<tr>
  <form>
  <td> ${product.getProductName()}</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="productName" value=${product.getProductName()}>
  <td>${product.getPrice()}</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="productPrice" value=${product.getPrice()}>
  <td>
    <input type="button" onclick="makeOrder()" value="Make order"/>
  </td>
  </form>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function makeOrder(){
  window.open("/user/makeOrder","","height=250,width=400,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,menubar=no");
}
```

How can I pass a variable ProductName and ProductPrice to popup window "/user/makeOrder" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quickest way to pass data to a popup window I created using window.open()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830347/quickest-way-to-pass-data-to-a-popup-window-i-created-using-window-open)

Comment: I cant solve my problem .

Comment: Nastya, your question is very broad and as it reads, it has been answered in another duplicate question. The answer you have here is *very& different from the answer that was given on the other question though. But, because both of your problems only wanted to "pass value to popup window", both answers are valid. Perhaps you could make your question more specific? For example, maybe you could change the title to "pass value to popup window *without* javascript" or maybe "pass value to popup window *with* jQuery". Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `ProductName` and `ProductPrice` as query string to new `location`, then use `search`, `.split()`, `while` loop to set properties, values to an object.

```
function makeOrder(name, price){
  window.open("/user/makeOrder?ProductName=" + name + "&ProductPrice=" + price,""
 ,"height=250,width=400,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,menubar=no");
}
```

At newly opended `window`

```
var params = location.search.split(/\?|=|&/).filter(Boolean);
var obj = {}, i = 0;
while (i < params.length) {
  obj[params[i]] = params[++i];
  ++i;
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I get such address: /user/makeOrder?productName=undefined&productPrice=undefined

Comment: Have you modified `makeOrder` to accept parameters, and passed parameters to the function?

Comment: Yes, it is my parent page:
`<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeOrder(name,price){
      window.open("/user/makeOrder?productName="+name+"&productPrice="+price,"","height=250,width=400,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,menubar=no");
    }
  </script>

<input type="hidden" id="productName" name="productName" value=${product.getProductName()}>
 <input type="hidden" name="productPrice" value=${product.getPrice()}>
  <input type="button" onclick="makeOrder()" value="Make order"/>
`

Comment: And page makeOrder:
`<script>
        var params = location.search.split(/\?|=|&/).filter(Boolean);
        var obj = {}, i = 0;
        while (i < params.length) {
            obj[params[i]] = params[++i];
            ++i;
        }
        console.log(obj)
    </script>`

Comment: @NastyaGorobets No parameters appear passed to `makeOrder` at `onclick="makeOrder()` ? Included `js` at newly opened `window` inside `window.onload` handler.  plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/cz5oN4qCt4KkGTSmJZO0?p=preview

Comment: @NastyaGorobets _"Yes, it is my parent page:"_ Have you adjusted `js` to pass parameters when `makeOrder` is called?

Comment: yes, now it prints abc and 123 . how can i get from obj my productName and my pruductPrice ?  is it obj[0]  and obj[1]?

Comment: I like your answer, it's quick, simple, and easy. But, could you compare it with the answer [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830347) and say a possible advantage/disadvantage of using each method?

Comment: +2 If you take the time to do that^

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Approach at linked Question is perhaps simpler; defining variables globally at new `window`. Approach at post passes parameters as query string, then converts to object at new `window`; though it is not necessary to create an object, could parse and access varibables directly from query string. Not certain about advantages or disadvantages, though present solution address would include query string at `location.href` of opened `window`; linked solution would not adjust `location.href` of new `window`