# How to enable .click event if it is called from a function it should not be loaded if the page is loading directly

Tags: javascript

I want to save mass data of my HTML page so I wrote two functions the first one is to open the pages and close them within a time frame the function goes in at this way

```
function allsave(){
  //For getting all the links inside variable
  var list = document.getElementById("tableData").getElementsByTagName('a');
  var i;
  for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    const tab = window.open(list[i], "_blank");
    //To auto close the table
    setTimeout(() => tab.close(), 5000);

    if (tab.closed === true) {
      continue;
    }
  }
```

The second function is like this

```
function getTextAreaMass(){
  var data =document.getElementById('document').value;
  var parsedData = parseSingle(data);

    //For running the auto save function
      document.getElementById('save').click();

    }
```

Everything is working as expected but the problem is this if i load the page directly .click event from the second function is running and saving the page automatically I don't want it to happen the .click event from the second function should only run if I am calling the first function but if I put the event in the first function then also the page is not auto loading how to solve this issue?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir How to do that? any code samples?

Comment: Chack this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830347/quickest-way-to-pass-data-to-a-popup-window-i-created-using-window-open). You could set a variable in the `tab` that will prevent the event from getting set. You only set the event listener if the variable is `undefined`: `if(!my_special_setting) { // set event here }`.

Comment: Where/When are you calling the method  `getTextAreaMass`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The answer which you have given was right i was about to accept the same can you post that once again i was in some power failure

Comment: @ArunVM I think the one using the variable is much better. Using hashes may not work if the link already uses hashes. I'm gonna change the answer to use a variable and notify. If it still work then accept. Ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a variable like in this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830347/quickest-way-to-pass-data-to-a-popup-window-i-created-using-window-open). You only set the click event listener if the variable is `undefined`. And when calling `window.open` you should set the variable so that it will have a (truthy) value in the new window, thus no event listener is set.

**Example:**

You set the event listener if the variable, say, `doNotSetListener` is `undefined`:

```
if(!doNotSetListener) {
    function getTextAreaMass() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And you should call `window.open` and then set the value of `doNotSetListener` to `true`:

```
const tab = window.open(list[i], "_blank");
tab.doNotSetListener = true;
```

Comment: Yeah, this is working but can you tell me why I should use this instead of the hash method?

Comment: @ArunVM Sorry for the late response! The hash won't work if the urls already have a hash in them. For example if `list[i]` is `"www.example.com/something#some_hash"` then when you append to it `#setListener` it will break the url: neither `some_hash` nor `setListener` will work as `location.hash` is now `"#some_hash#setListener"` which is obviously `!==` to `"setListener"`. Also the page might be relying on hashes to work properly so it's better to just leave the hash alone and use variables instead.