# Pass parameters Object with this.router.navigateByUrl in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, data-sharing

I want to pass my parameter to of the function to my below method in Angular so that I can use it another tab

```
  showReports(data) {
    console.log(data);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('').then(result => {  window.open('/selected', '_blank'); });
  }
```

So how to pass the data in above function to `navigateByUrl` method in Angular?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl

Answer (score 1):

```js
constructor(private router:Router){ }

public showReports(data) {
    console.log(data);

    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      state: {
        customData: data
      }
    };

    this.router.navigate(
      ['selected'],
      navigationExtras
    );
  }
```

And then in another Angular component, you can access it using `history` API.

```js
window.history.state.customData
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help,the above code doesnot work when i open the route in new tab, the customdata comes as undefined @Prabh

Comment: Are you using Angular's router to open new tab? If not, then try using window object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830388/5171009