# Passing markdown value into another page in Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I have a markdown editor in View A which is showing the result in the current View. I'm trying to pass a result to another page which is View B. In the View A, a button exist to share the markdown result to View B. I'm using texarea for typing text and I have vue-markdown which converts the textarea input to markdown result. My plan is to pass the same vue-markdown result into View B.

View A

```
      <template>
        <div class="boxA">
         <form id="add-form" >
             <div>
                <button class="btn-share"@click="shareToPublic()"> 
                Share To View B</button>
             </div>
             <div>
                <input type="text" v-model:value="saveNotes.title">
             </div>
                <textarea v-model:value="saveNotes.text" name="content"></textarea>
          </form>
                <vue-markdown :source="saveNotes.text" >
                </vue-markdown>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script lang="ts">
    import VueMarkdown from 'vue-markdown';
    import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component({
      components: {
        VueMarkdown,
      }
    })
    export default class MarkdownNotePad extends Vue {
    
      noteList: any[] = [];
    
      saveNotesDefault: NoteType = {
        title: '',
        text: '',
      };

     shareToPublic(){
        const routData = this.$router.resolve({name:'ViewB'});
        window.open(routData.href, 'viewB')
      }
    </script>
```

View B

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      {{ View A markdown result }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Component, Vue} from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class SharePublic extends Vue {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1. Passing data through window.open**

You can pass data through to a new window created with `window.open`.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830388/3688864).

View A

```
shareToPublic() {
    const routData = this.$router.resolve({name:'ViewB'});
    var viewB = window.open(routData.href, 'viewB');
    viewB.notes = saveNotes.text;
}
```

View B

```
notes: string | null = null;

mounted() {
    this.notes = window.notes;
}
```

**Option 2. Passing data between components**

Take a look at [Passing Data to Child Components with Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) and how to use them with vue-property-decorator with [@Prop](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#Prop).

1. You need to reference component B in your ts:

`import ComponentB from "./ComponentB.vue`;

2. You need to reference component B in your markup and pass the markdown:

`<component-b :markdown="saveNotes.text"></component-b>`

3. You need to add a prop to component B

`@Prop(String) markdown: string | null = null;`

**Option 3. Persisting data between components**

You should take a look at [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store) which lets you persist data between components.

As far as I understand your question. You will want to do something like this:

User navigates to View A
User types some text
User clicks Share
*Vuex stores the text*
User navigates to View B
*Vuex reads the stored text*

index.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        notes: null
    },
    mutations: {
        updateNotes(state, notes) {
            state.notes = notes;
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store: store,
})
```

View A

```
shareToPublic(){
    this.$store.commit("updateNotes", this.saveNotes.text);
    const routData = this.$router.resolve({name:'ViewB'});
    window.open(routData.href, 'viewB')
}
```

View B

```
get notes() {
    return this.$store.state.notes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For some reason Component B is showing inside of Component A. Basically, when I press a button, whatever I typed in the Component A is going to display in Component B which Component is a different window display from Component A.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're after. Are component A and component B completely seperate?

Comment: @LeoNakamura If you still need help, edit your question to clarify the relationship between the components

Comment: @Showjep Sorry, perhaps my question was wrong. I re-edit my question.

Comment: @LeoNakamura Updated