# Navigate to another page with data in a React Component after fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am new to React + typescript and is trying to use "react-router-dom" to make a login component to communicate with my backend server.

Basically I am trying to make a class "Login" that, upon submitting a form, will trigger a fetch request to my server. If the response from my server is OK, I will then navigate to another page with the input data.

Everything works fine until I try to navigate to my second page. The thing is, I don't want the login credentials to appear in the url, and the rule of hooks is preventing me from using the navigate hook after checking the status code of my fetch response.

Does anyone have an idea about how I can achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: added current code

```
interface MyProps{
}
interface MyStates{
  username: string,
  password: string
}

class Modal extends React.Component<MyProps, MyStates>{
  constructor(props: MyProps){
    super(props);
    this.state = {username: '', password: ''};

    this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
    this.handleLoginSubmit = this.handleLoginSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleUsernameChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    this.setState({username: event.target.value});
  }

  handlePasswordChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value});
  }
  
  handleLoginSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var request = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password})
    }
    fetch('login',request)
    .then(response => {
      if(!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);
      else {
//        window.location.replace('/AfterLogin.html?name=' + this.state.username)
      }
    })
  }
  render(){
    return <div className='Modal'>
          
            <form onSubmit= { this.handleLoginSubmit }>
              <label>
                Username
              <input type='text' name='username' value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsernameChange} />
              </label>
              <p/>
              <label>
                Password
              <input type='password' name='password' value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} />
              </label>
              <p/>
              <button> Sign In</button>
            </form>
          
        </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share a code example for what it is you are trying to do. It's near impossible to help debug code we can't see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How do you want the URL to appear? Do you need to send the `this.state.username` to the next page? Does this `Modal` component receive any route props? In other words, is it rendered by a `Route` or decorated with the `withRouter` HOC to get passed a `history` object to use for navigation?

Comment: Basically I want to make a React component that can pass the login credentials to another page without having it appear in the URL for security reasons. I could use any external components but am not sure what is the most popular way of doing so

Comment: Sure, you can send it via route state. What version of `react-router` are you using? From your project's directory run `npm list react-router react-router-dom`.

Comment: I'm using version 6.0.2

Comment: What is `AfterLogin.html`? Is this a route/component being rendered by your app?

Comment: Yes. It's a route within the same working directory that holds a separate page.

Comment: So it isn't a route your app is rendering? If it's a separate webpage then you can't use your React app's routing to send data. You may find this [SO post/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830347/quickest-way-to-pass-data-to-a-popup-window-i-created-using-window-open) useful/helpful.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for the link. I ended up with a workaround that passes password parameters in the url, but after a private key encryption. I do hope to see if there's an easy way for React to send data secretly within different pages of same domain though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `useNaviate()` hook from react router dom.

```
const navigation = useNavigate()
// OnLogin Successfully
navigation("/home",{state :{ name : "raeon"}, replace:true})
```

You need to pass two arguments. First one is link you want to navigate to. And in the second param you have to pass object with key, `replace` and 'state`. React more about this on : https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate

Comment: "and the rule of hooks is preventing me from using the navigate hook after checking the status code of my fetch response"

buddy, calling useNavigate() inside of that else block is obviously going to cause that error.